# Sticky header - 2 logos showing on initial load

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a header strip on my website that's sticky. It has a transparent background and a white logo. As you scroll down, the background changes to white and the logo changes to a navy blue version.

However, on initial load, both the logo images are showing until you scroll about the page and it works perfectly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction and show me how to hide the navy logo on load and only show it for the first time when the user has scroll down?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```js
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    jQuery(".header-container-fluid").addClass("headeractive");
    jQuery('.logo-navy').show();
    jQuery('.logo-white').hide();
  } else {
    //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
    jQuery(".header-container-fluid").removeClass("headeractive");
    jQuery('.logo-navy').hide();
    jQuery('.logo-white').show();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-container-fluid {
  position: fixed;
  width 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 125px;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-container-fluid.headeractive {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.logo-container {
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.logo-container img {
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.logo-container:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid header-container-fluid" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 logo-container">
        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
          <div class="logo-white"><img src="https://seedcreativity.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/logo-jonas-white.png" alt="Jonas Sports Logo" title="Jonas Sports"></div>
          <div class="logo-navy"><img src="https://seedcreativity.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/logo-jonas-navy.png" alt="Jonas Sports Logo" title="Jonas Sports"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 2000px; background-color:#304FE0;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to hide `.logo-navy` by default when the page loads:

```
.logo-navy {
  display: none;
}
```

Also note that you can DRY up the JS logic by using `toggleClass()` and `toggle()`:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrolledDown = $(window).scrollTop() > 50;
    $(".header-container-fluid").toggleClass("headeractive", scrolledDown);
    $(".logo-navy").toggle(scrolledDown);
    $(".logo-white").toggle(!scrolledDown);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-container-fluid {
  position: fixed;
  width 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 125px;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-container-fluid.headeractive {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.logo-container {
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.logo-container img {
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.logo-container:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.logo-navy {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid header-container-fluid" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 logo-container">
        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
          <div class="logo-white"><img src="https://seedcreativity.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/logo-jonas-white.png" alt="Jonas Sports Logo" title="Jonas Sports"></div>
          <div class="logo-navy"><img src="https://seedcreativity.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/logo-jonas-navy.png" alt="Jonas Sports Logo" title="Jonas Sports"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 2000px; background-color:#304FE0;"></div>
```

Comment: Ahh! I thought I might have been missing something simple!! I didn't realise the JQ would override the display:none: like that :) Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Also note that I just added an edit to show how to DRY up the JS a little.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the CSS code below for init

```
.logo-navy {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add to the CSS:

```
.logo-container .logo-navy {
   display: none;
}
```